# consuming a webservice in vb 2010

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, web-services

Sorry, it's been a while since I've worked with MS web service clients.  I'm using web developer 2010.  I created a web method that returns:

```
-<NewDataSet xmlns=""> -<TC diffgr:id="TC1" msdata:rowOrder="0">
 <SalesN>25</SalesN> 
  <PctDiscount>0.0000</PctDiscount> 
   <SubDiscount>0.0000</SubDiscount> 
 </TC> 
<TC diffgr:id="TC2" msdata:rowOrder="1"/> 
 -<TC diffgr:id="TC3" msdata:rowOrder="2"> 
  <PctDiscount>0.0000</PctDiscount> 
   <SubDiscount>0.0000</SubDiscount> 
   <SalesT>685.89</SalesT> 
</TC>
...
```

I'm trying to get to the information in SalesN and SalesT

My aspx button click looks like this:

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim date1 As String
    Dim date2 As String
    Dim myString As String
    date1 = TextBox1.Text
    date2 = TextBox2.Text

    Dim myreport As New ServiceReferenceReport.wsReportEngineSoapClient
    myreport.GetSalesTotals(date1, date2)
End Sub
```

Can someone point me to a tutorial, or refresh my memory?

I've load a datagrid and can't seems to parse out the data elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it...

```
    Dim date1 As String
    Dim date2 As String
    date1 = TextBox1.Text
    date2 = TextBox2.Text

    Dim returnds As New DataSet
    Dim myreport As New ServiceReferenceReport.wsReportEngineSoapClient
    returnds = myreport.GetSalesTotals(date1, date2)
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim current As String
    For i = 0 To returnds.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1
        If IsDBNull(returnds.Tables(0).Rows(i)("SalesN")) = True Then
            current = ""
        Else
            current = CStr(returnds.Tables(0).Rows(i)("SalesN"))
            Label1.Text = current
        End If
        If IsDBNull(returnds.Tables(0).Rows(i)("SalesT")) = True Then
            current = ""
        Else
            current = CStr(returnds.Tables(0).Rows(i)("SalesT"))
            Label2.Text = current
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```